# Git: Pulling changes from new remote (unrelated histories)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have inherited a new project that is currently live and working correctly. It had it's own repo. Upon handover, a new repo was created with the same code.

Using the new repo I was able to correctly clone on my localhost and confirm it's working.

I now want to pull a commit from the new repo to the live server. I have changed the remote to the new repo (I do not have access to the old repo) using:

`git remote set-url origin the/new/git/repo`

On the server When I do a:

`git pull origin master`

It complains about unrelated histories which makes sense because it's a new repo. When I do a:

`git diff origin/master`

I get a list of files and the corresponding code that has 'changed'. I can see the file that I have changed. Other files have differences that I did not touch but on the live files these changes are already there?

Am I safe to do a:

`git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`

Or is there potential for issues? If something does go wrong, is it possible to undo even though it's a new remote?

Comment: If you keep a backup you can always just experiment with the option. As long as you don't push anything you can't really do any damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try the following:

```
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

then, there might be a condition where you might want to compare the diffs in the branches. That can be a bit misleading as there is something to compare but the commit histories are different.

In that case, you solve it by using the following:

```
git merge origin use-ts-bot --allow-unrelated-histories
```

as you need to merge the disparate branches which is now disabled by default in git but can be enabled with the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag.

I have taken the words right out of [this](https://medium.com/@spences10/git-allow-unrelated-histories-a39a3814b981) article. Please read it for more clarity.

Comment: That's not what he's asking. He's already found this option but is asking whether it can cause any issues.